# What is the purpose of using the word "automagically" when we already have "automatically"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

Is there a difference between the two? I see it used regularly in the tech community to mean automatically.

Has the word been adopted into any recognised dictionary?

For example:

> That was the day I officially stopped
>   caring what version Chrome is. I mean,
>   I care in the sense that sometimes I
>   need to check its dogtags in battle,
>   but as a regular user of Chrome, I no
>   longer think of myself as using a
>   *specific version* of Chrome, I just …
>   use Chrome. Whatever the latest
>   version is, I have it **automagically**.

-- [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) ([The Infinite Version](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-infinite-version.html))

Comment: Look at the programming language haskell. It does a lot of stuff automagically. It's really a way to just say it works, without a technical reason as to why.

Comment: There's a "law" coined by Artur C. Clarke in the early '70s which says "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Comment: I would rather we would just stuck to "automatic". For me it feels like "automagic" is unwittingly obfuscating rather than enlightening. It carries pretense and mystification and could be roughly translated to "by means so clever you wouldn't understand". I would discourage it, especially when you're communicating to an educated audience (like in tech. manuals) and would just say "automatically". And if you want to stress uniqueness or novelty of the solution you can do so in a way that's enlightening and inspiring.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This comes from computer jargon, and [the jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/automagically.html) lists it.

> Automatically, but in a way that, for some reason (typically because it is too complicated, or too ugly, or perhaps even too trivial), the speaker doesn't feel like explaining to you. See [magic](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/magic.html). “The C-INTERCAL compiler generates C, then automagically invokes cc(1) to produce an executable.”
>
> This term is quite old, going back at least to the mid-70s in jargon and probably much earlier. The word ‘automagic’ occurred in advertising (for a shirt-ironing gadget) as far back as the late 1940s.

Automagically implies certain 'magic' going on behind the scenes.

In Atwood's example it might be a bit too much or just appropriate. It depends on when it was written: today automatic updating is common, but it did not use to be. In the days when it was not common the term "automagically" fits very nicely.

It also fits well to describe the change, if the process required user action before, you can say that now it happens *automagically*.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice answer. I did not know that the word had its origins in the '70s as I have only really seen it used in the last few years around the same time people started talking about mashups!

Comment: @Treffynnon, you are welcome. Jargon file is a nice resource, it is not too big and reading through it provides some really valuable linguistic background for programmers' culture and language (of course the early days of it) and I can only recommend it.

Comment: As a long-time computer geek who has actually submitted items to the jargon file, I'd say that if Atwood is using the term in a reasonable manner, he must be referring to Chrome automatically updating itself and any plugins without any user interaction. Most technical users would object to this, since they'd want to be notified and probably have to give approval for an update -- even Apple's very-consumer-oriented App Store requires you to OK an update.

Comment: Even automatically checking on startup to where you need only approve to (more or less instantly, especially with the tiny download size mentioned in the linked article) start the new version rather than the old would qualify in my book, compared to the 'old days' of manual upgrading, browser downloads larger than today's _full_ versions, and slower connections.

Comment: I'd defend Jeff's usage of the term here, Chrome doesn't 'just autoupdate', it does it in fancy ways, to achieve something that many people would not believe was reasonably possible if they weren't doing it (Like 70-oddkb updates, for example)

Comment: +1; This answer briefly touches on the jargon usage of the word _magic_ which is very different from what you would expect via Harry Potter. The key to understanding _automagically_ is in understanding _magic_.

Comment: +1 for referring to the jargon file. I'm a bit suspicious of its authority -- I think it contains a lot of folk etymology! -- but it is endlessly entertaining.

Comment: @MrHen, that's why I did provide link in the quote. @senderle, folk etymology is good, remember as Borges said, words are symbols of shared memories.

Answer (score 16):

The meaning reported from the NOAD is the following:

> (especially in relation to the operation of a computer process) automatically and in a way that seems ingenious, inexplicable, or magical.

As per the origin, the dictionary reports it's 1940s, from the blend of *automatically* and *magically*.

The meaning of the word is different from the meaning of *automatically*, and the word is generally used in a specific context.

Answer (score 6):

There's an implication of a deep appreciation of the cleverness of whatever secret process makes the system work.  So it goes beyond just, "I don't understand how this works", to "This is really cool, even though I don't understand how it works".

Comment: I always understood it to mean "This is cool,I understand it or think I do, but I can't be bothered explaining it to you as you might not get it anyway"

Comment: @WOPR that's exactly why I dislike the term "automagically". For me it feels like it carries a sense of pretense (possibly unintentional) as in "you wouldn't understand". As a software developer I prefer to know exactly how things work (or at least have an ability to look it up if a need arises) and I feel that "black box" code or technology that is described as "it just works", "don't touch", "automagic" is asking for trouble or at least demonstrating pretense and ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a serious word. It's used jokingly, implying that something happens both automatically and as if by magic.

Comment: No, it is not used jokingly, see my references (though humor, irony and wit is common, still most of the jargon entires have very well defined meanings and were/are common in serious communication).

Comment: This word has a considerable history in computer geek circles and really is distinct from "automatically" in that it also implies cleverness or even "deep magic".

Comment: Guess I move in different geek circles. ;)